# rpy2 to subset RS4 object (expressionSet)

Tags: r, subset, rpy2, r-s4

I'm building an ExpressionSet class using rpy2, following the relevant [tutorial](http://rpy2.readthedocs.org/en/version_2.7.x/generated_rst/s4class.html) as a guide. One of the most common things I do with the Eset object is subsetting, which in native R is as straightforward as

```
eset2<-eset1[1:10,1:5] # first ten features, first five samples
```

which returns a new ExpressionSet object with subsets of both the expression and phenotype data, using the given indices. Rpy2's RS4 object doesn't seem to allow direct subsetting, or have rx/rx2 attributes unlike e.g. RS3 vectors. I tried, with ~50% success, adding a '_subset' function (below) that creates subsets of these two datasets separately and assigns them back to Eset, but is there a more straightforward way that I'm missing?

```
from rpy2 import (robjects, rinterface)
from rpy2.robjects import (r, pandas2ri, Formula)
from rpy2.robjects.packages import (importr,)
from rpy2.robjects.methods import (RS4,)

class ExpressionSet(RS4):
    # funcs to get the attributes
    def _assay_get(self): # returns an environment, use ['exprs'] key to access
        return self.slots["assayData"]
    def _pdata_get(self): # returns an RS4 object, use .slots("data") to access
        return self.slots["phenoData"]
    def _feats_get(self): # returns an RS4 object, use .slots("data") to access
        return self.slots["featureData"]
    def _annot_get(self): # slots returns a tuple, just pick 1st (only) element
        return self.slots["annotation"][0]
    def _class_get(self): # slots returns a tuple, just pick 1st (only) element
        return self.slots["class"][0]

    # funcs to set the attributes
    def _assay_set(self, value):
        self.slots["assayData"] = value
    def _pdata_set(self, value):
        self.slots["phenoData"] = value
    def _feats_set(self,value):
        self.slots["featureData"] = value
    def _annot_set(self, value):
        self.slots["annotation"] = value
    def _class_set(self, value):
        self.slots["class"]  = value

    # funcs to work with the above to get/set the data
    def _exprs_get(self):
        return self.assay["exprs"]
    def _pheno_get(self):
        pdata = self.pData
        return pdata.slots["data"]

    def _exprs_set(self, value):
        assay = self.assay
        assay["exprs"] = value
    def _pheno_set(self, value):
        pdata = self.pData
        pdata.slots["data"] = value


    assay = property(_assay_get, _assay_set, None, "R attribute 'assayData'")
    pData = property(_pdata_get, _pdata_set, None, "R attribute 'phenoData'")    
    fData = property(_feats_get, _feats_set, None, "R attribute 'featureData'")
    annot = property(_annot_get, _annot_set, None, "R attribute 'annotation'")    
    exprs = property(_exprs_get, _exprs_set, None, "R attribute 'exprs'")
    pheno = property(_pheno_get, _pheno_set, None, "R attribute 'pheno")


    def _subset(self, features=None, samples=None):

        features = features if features else self.exprs.rownames
        samples  = samples if samples else self.exprs.colnames

        fx = robjects.BoolVector([f in features for f in self.exprs.rownames])
        sx = robjects.BoolVector([s in samples for s in self.exprs.colnames])

        self.pheno = self.pheno.rx(sx, self.pheno.colnames)        
        self.exprs = self.exprs.rx(fx,sx) # can't assign back to exprs this way
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing

```
eset2<-eset1[1:10,1:5]
```

in R, the R S4 method "`[`" with the signature ("`ExpressionSet`") is fetched and run using the parameter values you provided.

The documentation is suggesting the use of `getmethod` (see http://rpy2.readthedocs.org/en/version_2.7.x/generated_rst/s4class.html#methods ) to facilitate the task of fetching the relevant S4 method, but its behaviour seems to have changed after the documentation was written (resolution of the dispatch through inheritance is no longer done).

The following should do it though:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
methods = importr('methods')
r_subset_expressionset = methods.selectMethod("[", "ExpressionSet")
```

Comment: That worked just fine, thanks @lgautier. For the record, I've posted my code in a follow-up answer.

Answer (score 0):

with thanks to @lgautier's answer, here's a snippet of my above code, modified to allow subsetting of the RS4 object:

```
from multipledispatch import dispatch 

@dispatch(RS4)
def eset_subset(eset, features=None, samples=None):
    """
    subset an RS4 eset object
    """
    features = features if features else eset.exprs.rownames
    samples  = samples if samples else eset.exprs.colnames

    fx = robjects.BoolVector([f in features for f in eset.exprs.rownames])
    sx = robjects.BoolVector([s in samples for s in eset.exprs.colnames])  

    esub=methods.selectMethod("[", signature="ExpressionSet")(eset, fx,sx)
    return esub
```